# Gap between images?

Tags: html, css

See the example here:

http://users.telenet.be/prullen/portfolio.html

I've tried setting my images to display:block -

```
display: block;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
```

but that didn't work.

I also tried adding

```
 visiblity:hidden;overflow:hidden;height:0;font-size:1px;line-height:0px
```

to the

```
 <div style="clear:both"></div>
```

but none of these work.

Does anyone know what the cause may be? If possible, clear:both should stay for IE7 compatibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick fix for [given page](http://users.telenet.be/prullen/portfolio.html):
Add `float:left` to `.item` css block.

Comment: Or, even better, `display: inline-block;` to the same `.item` element. But you'll need to keep the `width: 100%;` css property.

Comment: Why is display:inline-block better? Can we have both (for fallback)?

Comment: You have to clear the floats after floated elements (in some cases). Have a look [here](http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/).

Answer (score 4):

Try putting them in a div with a class name '.row', and setting the line height to 0.

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
    <img src="img1.png" />
    <img src="img2.png" />
    <img src="img3.png" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.row {
    line-height: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your paragraph tag is what is causing the gap on top and bottom. The default for paragraphs (in chrome) is:

```
p {
display: block;
-webkit-margin-before: 1em;
-webkit-margin-after: 1em;
-webkit-margin-start: 0px;
-webkit-margin-end: 0px;
}
```

simply setting the margin to 0 will fix your problem:

```
p { margin: 0px; }
```

Answer (score 1):

If the gap you're talking about is the vertical gap between the images, then your problem is the top margin on the `<p>` in the second `.item .description`. It's the element giving the gap.

```
.description p { margin-top: 0 }
```

Alternately:

```
<div class="description">
    <p class="first">Description goes here.</p>
</div>

.description .first { margin-top: 0 }
```

Comment: That works, thaks. But is it possible to find the first element that is in the <div class="description"> div that has a margin-top, and set that to zero? As it may not always be a div.

Comment: I believe .description:first, but it's not cross-browser compliant. You can always go with class="first"

Answer (score 1):

Ok, tested a works.

Remove the `clear:both div` and set a float style to the first item.

**bad:**

```
<div class="item">
    [...]
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
<div class="item" style="border:red;">
    [...]
</div>
```

**good:**

```
<div class="item" style="float:left;">
    [...]
</div>
<div class="item" style="border:red;">
    [...]
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add `<div style="clear: both;" />` after your first `<div>`.

[Fixed code](http://pastebin.com/Wntrv0Cy)

Also you can delete it:

```
<div style="clear:both;visiblity:hidden;overflow:hidden;height:0;font-size:1px;line-height:0px;"></div>
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to do anything (fixed typo too).

Comment: Thanks, tried this in my live build but didn't work, then noticed you added a float to the description class too.

Comment: Maybe, but It is what you found, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Do your resets in CSS...

*{ padding: 0; margin: 0; }

Answer (score 0):

The `<p>` tag for the second item is pushing the entire div down by 1 line, because its default top and bottom margins are usually 1em. When you set its margins to zero, then the items will line up right on top of each other. You would want to set `<p>` or make a class for `<p>` to `margin-top: 0px`.